# How do I handle a no space left error in AWS Glue DataBrew?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

When running for 1 month's worth of data I get the below errors. In the advanced settings I have the maximum number of units set to the maximum of 10. What is the recommended approach to handle this?

```
An error occurred while calling o62075.collectToPython. No space left on device
```

```
An error occurred while calling o62081.pyWriteDynamicFrame. /tmp/blockmgr-9adbd7f0-0068-4244-bf85-3c59df19b610/33/temp_shuffle_4ec99ff1-e730-46ab-8b94-e35d51308aa6 (No space left on device)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the right direction about the units. Depending on your dataset size, the recommended approach is to increase the number of units for a given job. For all subsequent job runs, DataBrew allocate that number of units for processing.

Maximum you can allocate is 149 units. Link to official docs - [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/databrew/latest/dg/jobs.recipe.html)